# Как правильно получить текст с P

Tags: html, jquery, index

Перейду сразу к примеру..

**Имеются несколько таких блоков:**

```
<div class="caption">
   <p>тут описание данного блока</p>
   <a href="#" class="open-dec">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

При нажатии на ссылку "Подробнее" открывается содержимое тега `<P>` в всплывающем окне **magnificPopup** - пишу такой код jQuery:

```
var $link = $(".open-dec"),
    $self = $link.index(); //здесь по идеи номер элемента, но не знаю как получить

var service_api = $('.caption p:eq('+$self+')').text();
$link.magnificPopup({
    items: {
        src: '<div class="white-popup animated zoomInUp">'+service_api+'</div>',
        type: 'inline'
    }
});
```

переменная `$self` возвращает "-1" - по идеи там номер элемента, типа 0, 1, 2, 3 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядковый номер не обязателен, если известно положение элементов в блоке и оно не меняется:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.open-dec', function() {
  console.log($(this).prev('p').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">
   <p>тут описание данного блока 1</p>
   <a href="#" class="open-dec">Подробнее</a>
</div>
<div class="caption">
   <p>тут описание данного блока 2</p>
   <a href="#" class="open-dec">Подробнее</a>
</div>
<div class="caption">
   <p>тут описание данного блока 3</p>
   <a href="#" class="open-dec">Подробнее</a>
</div>
<div class="caption">
   <p>тут описание данного блока 4</p>
   <a href="#" class="open-dec">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ и внимание!

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, что из этого у меня получается: https://jsfiddle.net/3n9quwko/

Comment: Скрипт не с первого клика срабатывает и при клике на другие ссылки сначала открывает тест предыдущего блока..

Comment: @Maqsood, это я для примера событие `click` привёл, как достучаться до текста, а в вашем случае надо вот так https://jsfiddle.net/3n9quwko/1/